# Anyone know if there any free trial IDE for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Free trial or open source version for the following softwares?

- Visual Studio 2010
- Sharepoint 2010
- SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

VS & SQL Server have express editions.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2010 has many "Express" versions, for different languages - Visual C# Express 2010, Visual Basic Express 2010, and others.

SharePoint 2010 - I don't believe there is a free version of this, but if you have MSDN or TechNet subscription, you get a development-time-only version.

SQL Server has an express edition as well.  I'd recommend SQL Server 2008 R2, however - may as well use the latest unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

you can get visual studio 2010 akong with key from:
http://daffainfos.blogspot.in/2011/11/free-download-microsoft-visual-studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to download free trial of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 in this site: http://download.cnet.com/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-2010-Professional/3000-2212_4-10618634.html.